# How to retrieve data from sqlite from list view click and view on a different activity android studio

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

I am a newbie in the android studio and I am trying to make an attendance mobile app where:
- I can add students and view the list of students added
- Add events and view the list of events added
- Add attendance where I have a spinner, auto-complete text view, and a button. on the spinner, the event name is retrieving from the SQLite database table. and on the autocomplete text view, last names of the students is retrieving also from the table in SQLite DB.

My problem is I cant don't know how to view the list of students who are present at that event. I would want it to do when I click on the events listview, new activity will open and shows all the students who are present.

My student's table has StudentID (primary key, autoincrement), last name, first name, year.
Events table has EventId (primary key, autoincrement), event name, date, time.
Attendance Table : attendanceID(primary key, autoincrement),eventname, student last name.

I would really appreciate your help guys. here's my code.

### ViewEvents.java

```
package com.example.acer.finals;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewEvents extends AppCompatActivity{

    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    private ListView mylistView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewevents);

        mylistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        populateEventView();
    }

    private void populateEventView()
    {
        ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getEventsList();
        int numRows = data.getCount();
        if(numRows == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ViewEvents.this, "Event List Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                theList.add("Event Name: " + data.getString(1) + "\nDate: " + data.getString(2) + "\nTime: " + data.getString(3));
            }
        }
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
        mylistView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //set an onItemClickListener to the ListView
        mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String ename = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                Cursor data = myDB.getEventName(ename);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewEvents.this, Load_Attendance.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

### AddAttendance.java

```
    package com.example.acer.finals;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddAttendance extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spnrEvent;
    Button btnSave;
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCtv;

    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> all_Lname = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> AllNames_adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);
        spnrEvent = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrEvent);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        autoCtv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCtv);

        //ADAPTER
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        final Cursor event = myDB.getAllEvents();
        while(event.moveToNext())
        {
            String name = event.getString(1);
            names.add(name);
        }
        spnrEvent.setAdapter(adapter);

        //================================================

        all_Lname = myDB.getAll_Lname();
        AllNames_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, all_Lname);
        autoCtv.setAdapter(AllNames_adapter);

        //================================================

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String evname = spnrEvent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String lastname = autoCtv.getText().toString();

                if(evname.length() != 0 && lastname.length() != 0){
                    createAttendance(evname,lastname);
                    spnrEvent.setSelection(0);
                    autoCtv.setText("");
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(AddAttendance.this,"You must put something in the text field!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    public void createAttendance(String evname, String lastname){
        boolean insertData = myDB.createAttendanceTB(evname,lastname);

        if(insertData==true){
            Toast.makeText(AddAttendance.this,"Successfully Entered Data!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(AddAttendance.this,"Something went wrong :(.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

### Load_Attendance.java

```
    package com.example.acer.finals;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Load_Attendance extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    private ListView attendance_list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loadattendance);

        attendance_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.attendance_list);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        populateListViewAttendance();

    }

    private void populateListViewAttendance()
    {
        String name= "";
        ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getEventAttendance(name);
        int numRows = data.getCount();
        if(numRows == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Load_Attendance.this, "Attendance List Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            while(data.moveToNext())
            {
                theList.add(data.getString(1));
            }
        }
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
        attendance_list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
}
```

### DatabaseHelper.java

```
    package com.example.acer.finals;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by acer on 12/3/2017.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Finals";

    // Table Names
    private static final String StudentInfo = "StudentInfo";
    private static final String EventTB= "EventTB";
    private static final String AttendanceTB = "AttendanceTB";

    // StudentInfo Table - column names
    private static final String StudentID = "StudentID";
    private static final String LastName = "LastName";
    private static final String FirstName = "FirstName";
    private static final String Year = "Year";

    // TAGS Table - column names
    private static final String EventID = "EventID";
    private static final String EventName = "EventName";
    private static final String EDate = "EDate";
    private static final String Time = "Time";

    // NOTE_TAGS Table - column names
    private static final String AttendanceID = "AttendanceID";
    private static final String Event_Name = "EventName";
    private static final String Student_Lname = "Student_Lname";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    // Table Create Statements
    // createStudentInfo table create statement
    private static final String createStudentInfo = "CREATE TABLE " + StudentInfo + "("
            + StudentID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + LastName + " TEXT,"
            + FirstName + " TEXT,"
            + Year + " TEXT " + ")";

    // createEventTB table create statement
    private static final String createEventTB = "CREATE TABLE " + EventTB + "("
            + EventID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + EventName + " TEXT,"
            + EDate + " TEXT,"
            + Time + " TEXT " + ")";

    // AttendanceTB table create statement
    private static final String createAttendanceTB = "CREATE TABLE " + AttendanceTB + "("
            + AttendanceID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + Event_Name + " TEXT,"
            + Student_Lname + " TEXT "+ ")";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(createStudentInfo);
        db.execSQL(createEventTB);
        db.execSQL(createAttendanceTB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + createStudentInfo);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + createEventTB);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + createAttendanceTB);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean createStudentInfo(String lname, String fname, String year)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(LastName,lname);
        contentValues.put(FirstName,fname);
        contentValues.put(Year, year);

        long result  = db.insert(StudentInfo, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean createEventTB(String ename, String edate, String time)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(EventName,ename);
        contentValues.put(EDate,edate);
        contentValues.put(Time,time);

        long result  = db.insert(EventTB, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean createAttendanceTB(String evname, String lastname)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Event_Name,evname);
        contentValues.put(Student_Lname,lastname);

        long result  = db.insert(AttendanceTB, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    //returns all data from StudentInfo db
    public Cursor getStudentsList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + StudentInfo;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }
    //returns all events list
    public Cursor getEventsList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + EventTB;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    //Returns only the ID that matches the name passed in
    public Cursor getEventName(String ename){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + AttendanceTB +
                " WHERE " + EventName + " = '" + ename + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    //Returns only the ID that matches the name passed in
    public Cursor getEventAttendance(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * " + Student_Lname + " FROM " + AttendanceTB +
                " WHERE " + EventName + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    //GET ALL Events
    public Cursor getAllEvents()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={EventID,EventName};
        return db.query(EventTB, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    //spinner
    public ArrayList<String> getAll_Lname()
    {
        ArrayList<String> all_Lname = new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT " + LastName + " FROM " + StudentInfo;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (data.getCount() > 0)
        {
            data.moveToFirst();
        }
        while(!data.isAfterLast())
        {
            all_Lname.add(data.getString(0));
            data.moveToNext();
        }
        return all_Lname;
    }
}
```

### activity_viewevents.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### acivity_addattendance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Choose Event :"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spnrEvent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCtv"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autoCtv"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/autoCtv"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/autoCtv"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/autoCtv"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autoCtv"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spnrEvent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### activity_loadattendance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/attendance_list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an event you extract the event name of the clicked event. You then want to start an activity but passing the event name to that activity.

You can do this by adding an Intent Extra e.g. :-

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(ViewEvents.this, Load_Attendance.class);
            intent.putExtra("EVENT_NAME",ename); //<<<<<<<< ADD this Line
            startActivity(intent);
```

Then ***`Load_Attendance`*** could be :-

```
public class Load_Attendance extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    private ListView attendance_list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loadattendance);

        attendance_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.attendance_list);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        populateListViewAttendance(getIntent().getStringExtra("EVENT_NAME")); //<<<<<<<< invoke with retrieved event name

    }

    private void populateListViewAttendance(String name) //<<<<<<<< added parameter
    {
        ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getEventAttendance(name);
        int numRows = data.getCount();
        if(numRows == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Load_Attendance.this, "Attendance List Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            while(data.moveToNext())
            {
                theList.add(data.getString(1));
            }
        }
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
        attendance_list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
}
```

***`//<<<<<<<<`*** indicates changed/added lines of code

***Note this hasn't been tested and assumes that the existing code was working, there might be the odd error.***

P.S. you should be closing Cursors when finished with them.

---

### Edits after comments due to chain of failures.

The following is code based upon your code but simplified to the basics of what you want in regard to this question.

**That is a List of events is presented in a Listview, clicking on an Item produces a list of the attendees.**

However, this is all done within the same activity, the attendees on the clicked event are list in the log. In short this verifies that the basic process provided in the above answer works and rather the issues that you are having are very likely due to the data that you have in the database.

#### The Code

#### activity_main.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="acer.com.finals.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/EventsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Finals";

    // Table Names
    private static final String StudentInfo = "StudentInfo";
    private static final String EventTB= "EventTB";
    private static final String AttendanceTB = "AttendanceTB";

    // StudentInfo Table - column names
    private static final String StudentID = "StudentID";
    private static final String LastName = "LastName";
    private static final String FirstName = "FirstName";
    private static final String Year = "Year";

    // TAGS Table - column names
    private static final String EventID = "EventID";
    private static final String EventName = "EventName";
    private static final String EDate = "EDate";
    private static final String Time = "Time";

    // NOTE_TAGS Table - column names
    private static final String AttendanceID = "AttendanceID";
    private static final String Event_Name = "EventName";
    private static final String Student_Lname = "Student_Lname";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    // Table Create Statements
    // createStudentInfo table create statement
    private static final String createStudentInfo = "CREATE TABLE " + StudentInfo + "("
            + StudentID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + LastName + " TEXT,"
            + FirstName + " TEXT,"
            + Year + " TEXT " + ")";

    // createEventTB table create statement
    private static final String createEventTB = "CREATE TABLE " + EventTB + "("
            + EventID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + EventName + " TEXT,"
            + EDate + " TEXT,"
            + Time + " TEXT " + ")";

    // AttendanceTB table create statement
    private static final String createAttendanceTB = "CREATE TABLE " + AttendanceTB + "("
            + AttendanceID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + Event_Name + " TEXT,"
            + Student_Lname + " TEXT "+ ")";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(createStudentInfo);
        db.execSQL(createEventTB);
        db.execSQL(createAttendanceTB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + StudentInfo);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EventTB);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AttendanceTB);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean createStudentInfo(String lname, String fname, String year)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(LastName,lname);
        contentValues.put(FirstName,fname);
        contentValues.put(Year, year);

        long result  = db.insert(StudentInfo, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean createEventTB(String ename, String edate, String time)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(EventName,ename);
        contentValues.put(EDate,edate);
        contentValues.put(Time,time);

        long result  = db.insert(EventTB, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean createAttendanceTB(String evname, String lastname)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Event_Name,evname);
        contentValues.put(Student_Lname,lastname);

        long result  = db.insert(AttendanceTB, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    //returns all data from StudentInfo db
    public Cursor getStudentsList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + StudentInfo;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }
    //returns all events list
    public Cursor getEventsList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + EventTB;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    //Returns only the ID that matches the name passed in
    public Cursor getEventName(String ename){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + AttendanceTB +
                " WHERE " + EventName + " = '" + ename + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    //Returns only the ID that matches the name passed in
    public Cursor getEventAttendance(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT *  FROM " + AttendanceTB +
                " WHERE " + EventName + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    //GET ALL Events
    public Cursor getAllEvents()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={EventID,EventName};
        return db.query(EventTB, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    //spinner
    public ArrayList<String> getAll_Lname()
    {
        ArrayList<String> all_Lname = new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT " + LastName + " FROM " + StudentInfo;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (data.getCount() > 0)
        {
            data.moveToFirst();
        }
        while(!data.isAfterLast())
        {
            all_Lname.add(data.getString(0));
            data.moveToNext();
        }
        return all_Lname;
    }
}
```

Note that although this is similar there are a 2) important changes :-

- 1 the `onUpgrade` method rather than concatenating the table create SQL instead just concatenates the respective table name. The original `onUpgrade` method would fail.
- 2 As per the answer and comments the `getEventAttendance` method has been amended to take the *eventname* as a parameter and to select all columns from the attendance table.

#### MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
ListAdapter mEventListAdapter;
ArrayList<String> mEventList;
ListView mEventsListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mEventsListView = this.findViewById(R.id.EventsList);

    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    dbhelper.getWritableDatabase().delete("EventTB",null,null);
    dbhelper.getWritableDatabase().delete("StudentInfo", null,null);
    dbhelper.getWritableDatabase().delete("AttendanceTB", null,null);

    dbhelper.createEventTB("The Main Event","31/12/2017","10:30");
    dbhelper.createEventTB("The Normal Event","31/12/2017","10:30");
    dbhelper.createEventTB("The Minor Event","31/12/2017","10:30");

    dbhelper.createStudentInfo("Bloggs","Fred","2017");
    dbhelper.createStudentInfo("Smith","Tom", "2016");
    dbhelper.createStudentInfo("Thomas","John","2015");


    dbhelper.createAttendanceTB("The Main Event","Bloggs");
    dbhelper.createAttendanceTB("The Main Event", "Smith");
    dbhelper.createAttendanceTB("The Normal Event","Thomas");
    dbhelper.createAttendanceTB("The Minor Event","Thomas");
    dbhelper.createAttendanceTB("The Minor Event","Smith");

    Cursor csr = dbhelper.getEventsList();
    mEventList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        mEventList.add(csr.getString(1));
    }
    mEventListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mEventList);
    mEventsListView.setAdapter(mEventListAdapter);
    mEventsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String eventname = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.d("EVLIST_ITEMCLCK","You clicked Item at Position " + position + " and extracted Event name as " + eventname);
            logEventAttendance(eventname);
        }
    });
}

private void logEventAttendance(String eventname) {

    Cursor csr = dbhelper.getEventAttendance(eventname);
    Log.d("EVATTEND","Number of attendance rows extracted is " + csr.getCount());
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("EVATTEND", "Attendee is " + csr.getString(2) + " at Event " + csr.getString(1));
    }
}
```

}

This :-

- 1) does a very usual initialisation and then gets the ListView by it's ID.
- 2) Creates an instance of the database helper, empties the 3 tables (database and tables will be created for the first run of the App).
- 3) Add 3 Events.
- 4) Add 3 Students.
- 5) Add Attendances at Events **NOTE IT IS VITAL THAT EVENT NAMES AND STUDENT LAST NAMES EXACTLY MATCH THE RESPECTIVE EVENT NAME AND STUDENT NAME**

  - Note that using names as references is restrictive e.g. you couldn't have Student's Tom Smith and Fred Smith as you use the last name as reference.
  - Normally ID's are used for referencing/linking columns between tables.
- 6) get the EventList and convert it to an ArrayList.
- 7) Setup the ListAdapter to use the ArrayList of event names.
- 8) Tie the Adapter to the ListView
- 9) Add an onItemClick listener to the listview.
- 10) When an item is clicked the number of attendance rows for the event is displayed in the log and for each (if any) a log entry is made.

#### Output

The following is the output from the above after clicking each item in turn :-

```
12-12 04:58:53.014 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVLIST_ITEMCLCK: You clicked Item at Position 0 and extracted Event name as The Main Event
12-12 04:58:53.014 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVATTEND: Number of attendance rows extracted is 2
12-12 04:58:53.014 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVATTEND: Attendee is Bloggs at Event The Main Event
12-12 04:58:53.014 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVATTEND: Attendee is Smith at Event The Main Event


12-12 04:58:54.192 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVLIST_ITEMCLCK: You clicked Item at Position 1 and extracted Event name as The Normal Event
12-12 04:58:54.193 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVATTEND: Number of attendance rows extracted is 1
12-12 04:58:54.193 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVATTEND: Attendee is Thomas at Event The Normal Event


12-12 04:58:55.477 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVLIST_ITEMCLCK: You clicked Item at Position 2 and extracted Event name as The Minor Event
12-12 04:58:55.478 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVATTEND: Number of attendance rows extracted is 2
12-12 04:58:55.478 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVATTEND: Attendee is Thomas at Event The Minor Event
12-12 04:58:55.478 2860-2860/acer.com.finals D/EVATTEND: Attendee is Smith at Event The Minor Event
```

*Note this is intended to supplement the answer.*

Comment: hi sir Mike, this line.. the getIntent is in redline:

populateListViewAttendance(getIntent.getStringExtra("EVENT_NAME");

Comment: Ooops it should be `populateListViewAttendance(getIntent().getStringExtra("EVENT_N‌​AME"));`

Comment: i am having an error in my databasehelper.java sir :( it says ::
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Student_Lname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * Student_Lname FROM AttendanceTB WHERE EventName = 'Event Name: qqwde

___this line from database helper.java..
String query = "SELECT * " + Student_Lname + " FROM " + AttendanceTB +
                " WHERE " + EventName + " = '" + name + "'";

Comment: You need to separate the columns that you want in the resultant cursor with a comma (`*, Student_Lname`). However, * means all columns, so all you need is `*`.

Comment: Hi Sir Mike! Thank you for answering my questions all the time. I have taken out the * from my query.. It does open the new activity which is the load_attendance.. but it is not showing the list of students who are entered in the event. It only says "Attendance list is empty"   :(

Comment: Did you remove the line  `String name= "";` in the `populateListViewAttendance` method? leaving that line in would result in no rows being returned.

Comment: Yes Sir Mike, I had remove it :( but still it wouldn't show anything :(

Comment: I would appear that the underlying data is incorrect, see edited question.